# Is it possible to open a new tab in watir-webdriver?

Tags: ruby, firefox, watir, webdriver

The only thing that looks a bit like what I'm trying to achieve is [this](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/New+Browser+Windows), but this works only for IE... for firefox I found [that](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/FireWatir+Installation) information, so is it not possible to open tabs, just new windows?

And the attach method is accessing only already OPEN tabs/windows... Is there a way to decide to open a specific link in a new window/tab? I searched in the documentation, but I didn't find such a function...

Comment: What is the difference between opening a page in a new tab and in a new window? Why do you care if new window is opened in a tab or in a window? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'd like to try something like multithreading, automating a site... ok doesn't matter anymore...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok thats not a solution but a work-around:

I switch to ruby mechanize, is quite different to use, but allows to do multithreading and everything without a visible browser window...