# How do I open tabs using a Watir in ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, watir-webdriver

I'm trying to create additional tabs in Firefox using Watir webdriver. However, I'm not having much luck

After opening the browser:

`require 'watir-webdriver'
b =Watir::Browser.new`

I want to open up tabs but have been unable to figure out how to access the Open a New Tab button on the browser. How could I create a new tab then?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to open a new tab in watir-webdriver?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626789/is-it-possible-to-open-a-new-tab-in-watir-webdriver)

Comment: Selenium doesn't support opening tabs.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As already mentioned Selenium doesn't explicitly support opening of tabs, however there are 'workarounds' such as...

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
browser = Watir::Browser.new :ff
browser.goto 'http://the-internet.herokuapp.com'
browser.link(:text, 'A/B Testing').click(:command, :shift)
browser.windows.last.use
```

This will open the link in a new tab (on a mac) and focus it

Comment: I need to do ctrl+T for chrome on windows. This does not work - browser.some_link.click(:control, 'T') C:/blah/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/keyboard.rb:48:in `assert_modifier': "T" is not a modifier key, expected one of [:control, :shift, :a
        from C:/blah/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/keyboard.rb:25:in `press' Please help me to fix this.

Comment: I don't think you need the 't' to open link in new tabs, just the 'ctrl' and 'click'

Comment: oh, yes. ctrl + t is for new tab

Comment: but that only opens a new blank tab, you could just 'create'a new instance of the browser if that's all you need

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82763/discussion-between-carldmitch-and-stack1).

Answer (score 4):

You can use javascript :

```
require 'watir' # Crawler
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome   #or firefox in your case
browser.goto 'http://example.com'

browser.execute_script('window.open("http://example1.com")')
```

Answer (score 0):

Watir does not care if a new page opens in a new window or in a new tab, so use window switching API to switch to the new tab after open it.

http://watir.com/guides/windows/

Comment: while it navigate into another page from the first page would the cookies still remains @Li Xinyang?